# python soap 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'promotePrefixes'

Tags: python, soap-client

I am doing a SOAP web service call, the webservice is written by java and I want to call it use python, here is my code:

```
#_*_ encoding=utf-8 _*_
'''send message'''

import suds, logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><SMS type="send"><Message SmsID="UE01234567890123450" Bid="intuser" RecvNum="15611071911" Content="asdf" SendLevel="1"/></SMS>'    
logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)    
server = suds.client.Client("http://10.12.88.10:8081/SMSG/services/SMS?wsdl")    
server.service.AddSMSList('POWERU-SMS',xml)    
print(server)
```

It did not work, the result is :

> DEBUG:suds.client:sending to
>   (http://10.12.88.10:8081/SMSG/services/SMS?wsdl) message:      
>   
>         
>            POWERU-SMS
>            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><SMS
>   type="send"><Message
>   SmsID="UE01234567890123450" Bid="intuser"
>   RecvNum="15611071977" Content="asdf"
>   SendLevel="1"/></SMS>
>               DEBUG:suds.client:headers = {'SOAPAction': '""', 'Content-Type':
>   'text/xml; charset=utf-8'} DEBUG:suds.client:http succeeded: b'\r\n\r\n 
>   \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n
>   \r\n  \r\n
>   \r\n
>   \r\n  \r\n  \r\n    \r\n    \r\n 
>   \r\n  \r\n
>   \r\n
>   \r\n  \r\n  \r\n    \r\n    \r\n  \r\n
>   \r\n    \r\n
>   \r\n  \r\n  \r\n    \r\n    \r\n 
>   \r\n  \r\n
>   \r\n
>   \r\n  \r\n  \r\n    \r\n    \r\n 
>   \r\n  \r\n
>   \r\n      \r\n 
>   \r\n      \r\n    \r\n
>   \r\n    \r\n
>   \r\n    \r\n
>   \r\n    \r\n
>   \r\n    \r\n 
>   \r\n    \r\n
>   \r\n    \r\n
>   \r\n    \r\n
>   \r\n    \r\n
>   \r\n    \r\n
>   \r\n  \r\n  \r\n    \r\n
>   \r\n      \r\n      \r\n
>   \r\n      \r\n
>   \r\n        \r\n      \r\n    \r\n
>   \r\n      \r\n      \r\n
>   \r\n      \r\n
>   \r\n        \r\n      \r\n    \r\n
>   \r\n      \r\n      \r\n        \r\n      \r\n      \r\n        \r\n      \r\n    \r\n
>   \r\n      \r\n      \r\n
>   \r\n      \r\n
>   \r\n        \r\n      \r\n    \r\n 
>   \r\n  \r\n    \r\n
>   \r\n
>   \r\n  \r\n\r\n'
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "bsSMS.py", line 14, in
>   
>       server.service.AddSMSList('POWERU-SMS',xml)   File "C:\Users\Wang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py",
>   line 559, in **call**
>       return client.invoke(args, kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Wang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py",
>   line 618, in invoke
>       result = self.send(soapenv)   File "C:\Users\Wang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py",
>   line 658, in send
>       result = self.succeeded(binding, reply.message)   File "C:\Users\Wang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py",
>   line 696, in succeeded
>       reply, result = binding.get_reply(self.method, reply)   File "C:\Users\Wang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\suds\bindings\binding.py",
>   line 150, in get_reply
>       soapenv.promotePrefixes() AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'promotePrefixes'

```
***Repl Closed***
```

I don't know what's the problem, could anyone help me.I'll appreciate it very much.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Post the code of `bsSMS.py` (especially line 14). I guess you are sending a None variable to the library.

Comment: perhaps it helps to add the location. See:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30111292/error-in-python-webservice-client-using-suds